# Weird changes when trying to change color of textview in a list adapter, dynamically

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I have a listfragment which I am populating with a adapter extending Base adapter.
I want a textview in one particular to be of a different color.

This is my target: (Forgive me for the "Title" spelling, I was in a hurry)

[image]

However when I scroll the list up and down, textviews from different rows also change color randomly,like this:

[image]

I have tried with and without viewholders, with the same result. I can't seem to find out what the problem is.

This is my getView method

```
 @Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.shedrow, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        viewHolder.txt=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        viewHolder.txt2=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else
    {
          viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();

    }
    viewHolder.txt.setTypeface(tf);
    viewHolder.txt2.setTypeface(tf);
    viewHolder.txt.setText(schedStorage.getProgramTitle(position));

    if (position==0) 
    {
             viewHolder.txt2.setTextColor(color);
     viewHolder.txt2.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
    }

    viewHolder.txt2.setText(sTimes.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: it looks like you're only setting the text colour once, so once a view is set to green, its never being reset back to black if its used again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convertView is a reused View (Row). When you scroll up and down and the first row goes off screen, Android may choose to reuse it when new rows show on-screen. If it gets reused, the color of txt2 will still be set to green. To avoid this, you should set the color and Typeface of txt2 when position != 0.

```
if (position==0) {
   viewHolder.txt2.setTextColor(color);
   viewHolder.txt2.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
} else {
   viewHolder.txt2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
   viewHolder.txt2.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.NORMAL);
}
```